# Listener not starting after silent Installation

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, oracle12c

We proceed silent Installation Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Oracle Installation.
Listener Creation.
DB Creation.

All phase works fine .

But after listener creation , 
While checking listener status , not able to check the status of listener.

oracle@imslinux:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin$ lsnrctl status
oracle@imslinux:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin$ ls -lrt lsnrctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 0 Jul  7  2014 lsnrctl

Please let me know :

1.Why lsnrctl shows 0 bytes after listener creation?
2.Is lsnrctl support in Ubuntu 16.04.5 version?

Reference link : https://community.oracle.com/thread/3994336?start=15&tstart=0

[listener creation[image][image: ][1]]

Comment: Looks like the installation didn't relink properly, maybe; are other binaries also zero bytes? Were there any errors in the main installation log?

Comment: Seems relink log contain no error in it.

Comment: Let me attach a relink log

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. Please note the steps.

**Steps:**

For above we need to do changes in /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/lib/ins_net_server.mk file

Open /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/lib/ins_net_server.mk and search for Linking $(TNSLSNR).

Replace with $(TNSLSNR) -lnnz12 -lons

And proceed Installation issue is fixed.

oracle@imslinux:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 18-JAN-2019 04:52:50

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=imslinux)(PORT=1521)))

### STATUS of the LISTENER

Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                18-JAN-2019 04:52:45
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/imslinux/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=imslinux)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
oracle@imslinux:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs$